# Modernized Computer Modern

Tags: fonts

What about the mysterious Modernized Computer Modern font (mmo) designed by Alan Hoenig? Is it still downloadble? Has it been used somewhere, or withdrawn at all?

Comment: Where is this mentioned?

Comment: @cfr Possibly referring to [this (tugboat)](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb22-3/tb71hoenig-modern.pdf).

Comment: I'd ask CTAN admin and/or barbara, I think. (Based on the link @ScottH. provided.)

Comment: A CTAN search on "Hoenig" doesn't list anything promising, so I assume this font isn't there.  (Scanning the linked article, however, either I did a really rotten editing job, or someone else edited that article; it's in a proceedings issue, which is often a cooperative effort.  Sigh.)

Comment: I checked a 2002 CTAN copy but found no traces of these fonts :-(